# Белая тема в Unity 2019.2.20f1

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно поменять черную на белую (серую) тему в юнити

Сейчас у меня вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать вот так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://prnt.sc/sqrb4v

Comment: @Andrew Спасибо! а то чет не мог найти. Можешь если хочешь сделать ответ -- помечу решением :)

Comment: да не, вопрос плевый. Просто удали его, мне балов хватает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---Автор ответа в коментариях под вопросом---